# How to Set Background Image In Blackberry 7.1

Tags: java, blackberry, background

i am trying to set background image for Blackberry 9900 simulator, i have written code like below

```
BitmapField _bitmap ;
private int phoneWidth = Display.getWidth();
private int cellHeight = Display.getHeight();
 public MyScreen(){

     super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);

     final Bitmap background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("black.jpg");
     VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
         public void paint(Graphics g) {
             Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(phoneWidth, cellHeight);         
             background.scaleInto(scaled, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
             g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight,
                             background, 0, 0);
             super.paint(g);
         }
     };
     add(vfm);
 }
```

and iam getting output in simulator like this

[image]

i want the background image to fill complete background, any help will be appreciated, Thank u in advance.

Comment: As my knowledge, we need to re size the image according to screen the we can use your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is HERE

```
 g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight,
                             background, 0, 0);
```

you must draw scaled bitmap

```
 g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight,
                             scaled , 0, 0);
```

Comment: Can you mention scaled means....
Because drawBitmap() have syntax like
drawBitmap(int x, int y, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap, int left, int top)

Comment: thank u so much it worked :), if i have vertical scroll means how to extend background image??